# Fetching data from json file returns empty response

Tags: javascript, json

This is my problem because I never used json, always just database or objects in javascript.

I don't want JQUERY I need just plain javascript!

But now when I try to fetch some data from json file I get empty response:

```
function loadJSON(file, callback) {   

    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', file, true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200"){
            callback(xobj.responseText);
          }
    };
    xobj.send(null);  
 }
function load(){
    loadJSON("data.json", function(response) {
    var some_data = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(some_data);
  });  
}
```

data.json contains:

```
 {"cars":["Mazda", "BMW"],"myCar":"BMW"}
```

Basically I want to fetch cars and do something with it...
When I use object in javascript it is very easy but as I said I never used json so I really do not know what are problems in my code.

Comment: What happens if you log `response` as well as `some_data`?

Comment: Nothing. Same as some_data

Comment: What does the Network tab in your browser's developer tools say? Are you getting the data you expect in the response?

Comment: I guess no, I have idex.html, style.css, main.js where is js code and it shows just those 3 files no request for json file

Comment: you are not calling load() in your code

Comment: are you running it on server or do you just open html file?

Comment: @NoNameIamLame — If there's no request for the JSON file, then how is the callback triggering and logging the empty response?

Comment: @Mamun true, thats my problem....

Comment: XAMPP server  @xszaboj

Comment: @Quentin I didn't even call my function, and Idk why but when I write it in chrome console it just return empty response even tho function wasnt called

Comment: "when I write it in chrome console". What is "it" in this context? If you say it returned an empty response, did you check the network tab to see if the request returned a "200 OK" status?